# Mobile web app deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to create a limited version of my app on mobile.
My app is at www.accountingguru.in (appid:  accountingguru-india.appspot.com). It is using Servlets/GWT/Objectify 3.1
I am figuring out how to move forward with the design/development choices for a limited mobile app

What is a good url for Mobile User experience.

1. www.accountingguru.in/mobile
2. mobile.acccountingguru.in

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

1. It can be both if you properly set your domain names (and GAE mapping) and use some url rewriting. The first option might be easier from the authentication perspective.
2. If you use GWT/GAE it needs to be a common project if you want to have one GAE instance. In practical terms you can not have two different GWT projects and upload them to same GAE instance. As far as GWT goes - you can have two separate entry points: one for desktop and the other for mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have same url.

Use deferred binding to achieve different UI according to user.agent

1. Define a module .gwt.xml to detect the user.agent
2. On your applications's module use the return value to choose the appropriate implementation.

Have a look at the sample projects in gwt.